# How to know the version of rdesktop on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, rdp

I am very new to both Ubuntu and rdesktop. For our project, we are using rdesktop on Ubuntu 10.04, which I think is quite old, may need update.

As we could use terminal to use desktop

```
rdesktop RemoteServerIpAddress
```

Could anyone tell me how to check the version of the desktop that we are using?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

$ rdesktop 2>&1| grep Version

or

$ apt-cache showpkg rdesktop

I hope this can help you!

Comment: It works in my Ubuntu 12.04. But not in Ubuntu 10.04, which is a Dell WYSE Thin Client.